# Build a specific number with summation of a few limited numbers

Tags: algorithm, math

I am looking for an algorithm which can help me solve this problem:

I need to create an series which will tell me how can I get a number(Input) by additive multiplication of numbers in an array(Which can be used to build the number) by multiplying each with an integer.

Lets take a number "4" as example. Consider Array as [3,2]

So the algorithm should give an output as 0x3+2x2=4.

(I think my main problem is when I create the output I see 4 > 3 so my output array starts with [1,..] what can't work anymore.)

Comment: What other constraints are there?  Can they be negative? Do they have to be integers?

Comment: Just positive integers in the array and just need to build positive integers

Comment: This is impossible for the general case with the constraints given. Consider the goal of 3 and input of [2, 4]. There are no coefficients that will satisfy `2x + 4y = 3`. In general, if the greatest common denominator of the input array divides the goal number, a solution is possible, which will be trivial to compute via the Euclidean algorithm. More specifically, if there are two relatively prime integers in the input array, there is a valid solution for all integers.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with **[linear integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming)**

Given an array (vector) `c = (c1,c2,...,cn)` and a number `k`, you are looking `x = (x1,x2,...,xn)` such that `c [dot] x = k`, which is the matrix notation equivalent to `c1x1 + c2x2 + ... + cnxn = k`.

The optimization problem is:

```
find x1,...,xn that maximizes:
     c1x1 + c2x2 + ... + cnxn
subject to:
     c1x1 + c2x2 + ... + cnxn <= k
     x1 >= 0, x2>= 0, .... , xn >= 0
```

Note that integer programming is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), but there are pretty good algorithms to solve it nevertheless, and if you discard the requirement that x1,x2,...,xn should be integers, this problem is solveable pretty easily.

Comment: What do you mean should x1,x2,...,xn be else than integers? Do you mean it should be booleans so every number can just be used once?

Comment: @user3662339 No, if they can get any real-valued number (3, 4.3333, pi, ...)

Comment: Okay yes that would be way easier but this isn't possible :(

Comment: It's also pretty easy if x1...xn don't have to be nonnegative.  (This gives rise to a totally different class of ILP algorithms.)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the coefficients must be non-negative integers, one algorithm would be:

```
a*x + b*y = c
given c, x, y

for i = 0 to floor(c/x)
    if (i*x - c) % b == 0   // answer found
       b = (i*x - c) / b
       break;
next
```

Comment: Care to explain? Also, it seems like your algorithm is hardcoded for an array of length 2 (is it the case)? If it is the case - this is oversimplification of the problem.

Comment: Yes, since that's the question that was asked (solve a linear equation with two unknowns.

Comment: I don't see where it asks for two numbers, it says 'few limited numbers'. Only the example shows two numbers.